# python embedable

Tags: python

I want to embed python in .NET application,Iam using **python for .net** .I want to publish this application without external python dependency.I tried using following python versions

- iron python(it doesn't support python 3)
- nuget python(it's lighter than traditional python still heavy for me)
- nuget python-embed(I couldnt download it due to some error)

If there is any other python package or installer please recommend me
(in python 3 documentation there is a mention of python executable zip but I couldn't find it on net)